# Lucene 6.0! How to instantiate a BooleanQuery and add other search queries in it?

Tags: java, lucene, booleanquery

How to instantiate a BooleanQuery in Lucene 6.x ?
How to use Boolean Query to add other queries in it ?

In Lucene 4.x we use BooleanQuery as follow:

```
    BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
    booleanQuery.add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    booleanQuery.add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

How this can be achieved in Lucene 6.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

BooleanQuery is now immutable (you can read about the change in the [Migration guide](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/MIGRATE.html) and the linked JIRA issues).

Instead, you would now use `BooleanQuery.Builder`:

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
    .add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
    .add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
    .build();
```